# What is the difference between nordic, global, etc. firmware versions?

Tags: rom, sony-xperia-neo-v

[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1678690) I see various versions of the official 4.1.B firmware for the Xperia Neo V. What are the differences between nordic, central europe, etc. versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Languages support I guess, plus the build number targets the specific SI numbers found underneath the battery hence the differences between them, however minor they may be, to target the region itself.

Comment: Plus, regulatory domains - for the most common one, WiFi channels are limited to the first 12 in the USA, whereas 14 are available in Japan and 13 in most of the EU. These are legal, not technical limits, enforced by whatever technical authority exists in the given country (e.g. FCC in the U.S. of A.). Smartphone makers usually comply with these limits by providing different firmwares for different jurisdictions (of course, if there are multiple jurisdictions that are similar in those respects, you just might get a firmware labelled "Nordic" for DK+NO+SE+FI or "North America" for CA+US+MX).